# A try-catch block within a for-loop, first attempt exception goes to catch block, then continues to next loop iteration, second doesn't

Tags: c#, for-loop, try-catch

Try-catch block within a for loop. First try, exception goes to catch block within loop, continue within catch block throws it back to beginning of loop. But second time it hits an exception within the try block, it throws to the try-catch block around when the method was called, rather than staying within the loop

```
for (int count = 0; count < listCount; count++)
{
    try
    {
        var selectElement   = new SelectElement(pageElement);
        selectElement.SelectByText(pagevalue);
        break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException NSE)
    {

   driver.FindElement(By.Id("policyNumber")).SendKeys(policies[count]);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnOK")).Click();
        continue;
    }   
}
```

Would expect exceptions to always catch within try-catch block inside of method rather than jumping out to try-catch outside of method.

Comment: Maybe the exception being thrown is not a `NoSuchElementException` exception

Comment: You're right. Didn't notice that. The element had gone stale and was throwing a different exception. Thanks dcg

Answer (score 2):

You should add another `catch` in the end, to catch all `Exception` that you haven't account for.

Try-catch block within a for loop. First try, exception goes to catch block within loop, continue within catch block throws it back to beginning of loop. But second time it hits an exception within the try block, it throws to the try-catch block around when the method was called, rather than staying within the loop

```
for (int count = 0; count < listCount; count++)
{
    try
    {
        var selectElement   = new SelectElement(pageElement);
        selectElement.SelectByText(pagevalue);
        break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException NSE)
    {

   driver.FindElement(By.Id("policyNumber")).SendKeys(policies[count]);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnOK")).Click();
        continue;
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //Do something with other exception
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second exception was a different exception type than what's specified in the catch block.